# How do I specify a specific path for a Razor template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, template-engine

If I have the controller `HomeController` and action `Index()`, but I have my template in `Views/Index.cshtml` as opposed to `Views\Home\Index.cshtml` - is there a way for me to bypass the conventional loading mechanism to render the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can explictly tell in the `View` method from where to load the view. You just need to start your `viewName` parameter with `~/Views` and you also **have to write out** the `.cshtml` extension:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

However the MVC convention is that if you have views which don't belong to one specific controller then these views should go to the Views\Shared folder and from there they will be looked up.

Comment: Tried without ".cshtml" and I got: The view '~/Views/Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Index

Comment: It is not working without ".cshtml" extension. You have to use `return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");` as I've written in my answer.

Comment: Got it!  This limits me to using razor I assume?  Is there any way to do this so that the template resolver can still pick the engine?

Comment: It is not the `.cshtml` which matters. But you need to put the extension itself. So if you would use the aspx engine then you need to write `return View("~/Views/Index.aspx");`. If your template comes with a proper `ViewEngine` implementation then this should work.